# new sencha touch sdk tools

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a sencha touch application that I built using sencha touch 2.0. I created a custom build for this application using the sencha touch sdk tools-beta(1). I recently downloaded the sdk tools-beta3 after reading the recent blog post by on the sencha blog:

http://www.sencha.com/blog/behind-sencha-command-and-the-build-process

What I am wondering is how I use the technologies outlined in this blog post on my current application? The blog post talks about the micro-loader and HTML 5 Application Cache stuff. These things seem very intriguing to me and I would like to get them to work with my current application but I am confused on how to do that. Can anyone point me in the right direction? It almost seems like I have to run the command:

```
sencha app create MyApp /path/to/www/myapp
```

and then port over all my existing code. Is this the only way to use what seem like new technologies released in the beta 3 sdk tools? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding is simple.

The entire application is a 4-step process.

- Inside `microloader > development.js`

  => Use this file, when targeting the development environment (as against to production.js[PROD] and testing.js [TEST] environment).
  => It's always a good practise to include this file inside your `index.html` rather than directly linking to your main `app.js`
- Then, in your `app.json` file,

  => All the information about your application's structure can be found inside the `app.json` file. It includes all the path's to your javascript files, including app.js (the main starting application file) and also the stylesheets.
- `App.js`

  => This is the most important js file in your application. It's like the starter of your application. This is the file, wherein in the `launch( )` function, you mention your 1st primary view.
- Make sure that your application is following proper MVC structure and all the files are properly configured.

Comment: Currently, I have a MVC structure in my code, but from what you are saying it seems like I have to port over all my existing code into this new structure. Is that right?

Comment: Good. If your application structure is already in MVC format, just include the rest of things like `development.js`, `app.json` and properly configure them.

Comment: So I have to manually add the path+name to all js files into the app.json?